# Django template list not showing all the images

Tags: css, django, image, django-templates

I am working on a Django project and its a simple product website which will look like:
First page-
1.Electronics link
2.Toys link

Second page after clicking on the link:
For electronics I have 3 item listed and same for toys.
How to show images of different product once user will click on it along with the list of items.

I have index.html which will show 1.Electronics link,2.Toys link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "productApp/css/index.css" %}"
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to our online shoping portal</h1>           
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/electronics">Electronics<img src="productApp/images/electronics.jpeg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="/toys">Toys</a></li>
            <li><a href="/shoes">Shoes</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Product.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>      
        <title></title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "productApp/css/product.css" %}"
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
        <ul>
        <!-- <img src="{% static "productApp/images/electronics.jpg"%}"/> -->
            <li>{{product1}}</li>
            <li>{{product2}}</li>
            <li>{{product3}}</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't say that your question is clear enough, but the obvious issue with this code is the use of relative URLs. Add leading `/` to all your css and image file URLs.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Hi, I am sorry if my question is not clear enough. I want to display electronics image once user will click on electronics link and toys image once clicked on toys link. This is what I am unable to implement in my django template.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/electronics">Electronics</a>
    <a href="productApp/images/electronics.jpeg">
      <img src="productApp/images/electronics.jpeg"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should answer your question regarding to "how to order the html". But I want to mention that your way to define the href-paths is not the django-way.

How to [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files). 
How to [urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: Thank you for your help however still it doesn't resolve my issue. I have just started learning django so may be I need to learn it more before implementing it further.